# Como interpretar uma frase como "água de coco é bom"?

Tags: gênero

Em português brasileiro (pelo menos), é relativamente comum ouvir frases como

> Água de coco é bom
>
> Praia é bonito

etc. Nunca havia me passado pela cabeça que há um aparente desacordo de gênero entre o substantivo e o adjetivo dessas frases. O que é interessante é que elas parecem (para mim) mudar de sentido se há um acordo. Por exemplo, "praia é bonito" para mim soa como um juízo sobre praias em geral, enquanto que "praia é bonita" me parece como algo sobre uma praia específica. Por sinal, essa última variante sequer me soa muito gramatical: eu tenderia a dizer algo como "essa praia é bonita", ou "a praia é bonita", e provavelmente não colocaria o artigo em "a praia é bonito".

É interessante que há um fenômeno paralelo em francês: uma frase como "la plage est belle" (literalmente, "a praia é bela") se refere a uma praia em particular, enquanto que "la plage, c'est beau" (literalmente, "a praia, isso é belo") se refere ao conceito geral de praias. Uma frase como "la plage, c'est belle" é agramatical, pois o adjetivo "belle", feminino, deveria concordar com o "ce", que é masculino.

A minha pergunta é: esse fênomeno é bem compreendido, quer seja nas variantes culta ou coloquial da língua? O que eu disse faz sentido para falantes de outras variantes de português?

Comment: Geralmente são erros de concordância a menos que você esteja se referindo ao objeto de uma forma que haja uma sutil elipse ai "Praia é ((sempre) algo) bonito"

Comment: Também se diz em Portugal. «Praia é bonito» não me parece. Mas «praia é ótimo», «feijoada é muito bom». Assim de repente, tenderia a justificar isto como redução de «estar na/fazer praia é ótimo», «comer feijoada é muito bom».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo menos está bem documentado. Veja-se por exemplo o [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-concordancia-de-e-preciso-e-e-necessario/32671) (citando a gramática de Evanildo Bechara):

> 12) **É necessário paciência** – Com as expressões do tipo é necessário, é bom, é preciso, significando ‘é necessário’, o adjetivo pode ficar invariável, qualquer que seja o gênero e o número do termo determinado, quando se deseja fazer uma referência de modo vago ou geral. Poderá também fazer-se normalmente a concordância:
>
> - É *necessário* paciência.
> - É *necessária* muita paciência.
> - “O fato de ter sido *precisa* a explicação (...)” [AP.1, 424 n.o 25].
> - “Eram *precisos* outros três homens” [AM.1 *apud* RBa.1, 33].
>     É possível ainda, em tais casos, aparecer no singular o próprio
>     verbo da oração:
>
> “É doce ao velho / d’argentina voz” [GD *apud* SS.1, 254]
>
> Como acentua Barbadinho, a flexão de *necessária(s)* é mais frequente que a de *precisa*.

[A Infoescola](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/concordancia-nominal/):

> **g) É bom, é necessário, é proibido**
>
> 1- Essas expressões não variam se o sujeito não vier precedido de artigo ou outro determinante.
>
> *Canja é bom. / A canja é boa.*
>   *É necessário sua presença. / É necessária a sua presença.*
>   *É proibido entrada de pessoas não autorizadas. / A entrada é proibida.*

Veja-se também o [So Português](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint59.php).

Quando à explicação, esta geralmente é a de que está implícito um infinitivo como *haver*/*ter* ([Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-concordancia-de-e-preciso-e-e-necessario/32671), [Não Tropece na Língua: Lições e curiosidades do português brasileiro](https://books.google.nl/books?id=ARCFAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA220&dq=concord%C3%A2ncia%20%22%C3%A9%20preciso%22&pg=PA219#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Quanto a Portugal, como disse o Jacinto, «praia é bonito» não é geralmente usado, mas parece-me que é mais uma questão de essa aceção de «bonito» não ser usada em Portugal; poderia contudo dizer-se «praia é ótimo».

Apesar de as várias fontes que mencionei porem no mesmo saco *é preciso/necessário/proibido* no mesmo saco de *é bom/ótimo/gostoso*, repare-se que têm um comportamento sintático diferente:

> (1) É preciso muita fé, antes de mais.
>   (2) É precisa muita fé, antes de mais. [menos natural]
>   (3) ?Muita fé é precisa, antes de mais.
>   (4) *Muita fé é preciso, antes de mais.

Para se usar o masculino, é preciso que o sujeito surja depois de *é preciso*. A frase (3) só parece possível num contexto enfático.

> (5) Praia é ótimo. [=ir à praia]
>   (6) ?Praia é ótima.
>   (7) *É ótimo praia.
>   (8) *É ótima praia.

Neste caso o sujeito tem de vir primeiro. A frase (6) parece-me duvidosa, acho que é necessrio adicionar um complemento ao adjetivo: *ótima para qualquer coisa*.

Answer (score 1):

Eu diria que **"água de coco é bom pra saúde"**, mas provavelmente não diria que "água de coco é boa pra saúde".  Neste caso, entende-se que beber água de coco /é bom/faz bem/ pra saúde.  Mas posso dizer que "**a boa água de coco** deve conter pelo menos seis tipos de sais minerais", sempre preservando a concordância.

**Não vejo, contudo, uma situação em que eu dissesse que "praia é bonito"**.  E nem ouço tal uso na região do Brasil em que vivo. Eu poderia dizer "a praia tem um visual bonito" ou "uma praia é algo bonito de se ver".  Mas nunca "praia é bonito."